# Python/Open CV: Creating a video from cos image sequence, the video is empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video

I'm trying to create a video from cos images that I create but my produced avi video is empty.

I have to use cv2.VideoWriter(). The frames are shown properly by the created video is 0 bytes. Do you know how to fix this?

If I get a frame from an avi video, then I create successfully a new playable video.

Thank you in advance!

My code is

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

N=128
Icos_1 = np.zeros((N,N))
Icos_2 = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(0,N):
    for j in range(0,N):
        myPi = 2*math.pi/N
        th1 = 1*i + 3*j
        th2 = 2*i + 4*j
        Icos_1[i,j] = 255*(math.cos(myPi*th1))
        Icos_2[i,j] = 255*(math.cos(myPi*th2))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('sample_video.avi',fourcc, 25.0, (128,128))

or x in range(1, 100):
    if (x % 2) != 0:
        frame = Icos_1
    else:
        frame = Icos_2

    out.write(np.uint8(frame))
    cv2.imshow('frame',np.uint8(frame))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release video objects if job is finished
out.release()
```

Comment: if you use `np.uint8(frame)` to display on screen then why don't you use `write(np.uint8(frame))`

Comment: You also may not have the right codec installed or have the codec you want supported for writing the video.  What operating system are you using?  Have you also tried using MPEG-4 instead of XVID?

Comment: @furas It didn't work! Still the same result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

I have to use 0 as codec in `out = cv2.VideoWriter('sample_video.avi',0, 25.0, (128,128))`

The full code is:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

N=128
Icos_1 = np.zeros((N,N))
Icos_2 = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(0,N):
    for j in range(0,N):
        myPi = 2*math.pi/N
        th1 = 1*i + 3*j
        th2 = 2*i + 4*j
        Icos_1[i,j] = 255*(math.cos(myPi*th1))
        Icos_2[i,j] = 255*(math.cos(myPi*th2))

out = cv2.VideoWriter('sample_video.avi',0, 25.0, (128,128))

or x in range(1, 100):
    if (x % 2) != 0:
        frame = Icos_1
    else:
        frame = Icos_2

    out.write(np.uint8(frame))
    cv2.imshow('frame',np.uint8(frame))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release video objects if job is finished
out.release()
```

Comment: 0 pops up a window that allows you to choose the codec that is installed on your system. The actual solution to your problem is that you chose the right codec. Please update your post to let us know which codec you actually chose.

Comment: @rayryeng When running the `cv2.VideoWriter()` having 0 to codec actually my program runs properly. The program pops up a window if I set `0` also to frame rate. But here I have frame rate = 25.0fps so my program is working.